# java persistence memory leaks

Tags: java, jpa, memory-leaks

I have 1M rows in a table and I want to get all of them. But when I try to get all rows with jpa by pagination then I get java heap error. Do you think that am I missing something? Any advice

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter >= 0) {
   javax.persistence.EntityManager em = javax.persistence.Persistence
     .createEntityManagerFactory("MyPU")
     .createEntityManager();

   Query query = em.createQuery("select m from mytable m");
   java.util.Collection<MyEntity> data = query
          .setFirstResult(counter).setMaxResults(1000).getResultList();
   for(MyEntity yobj : data){
            System.out.println(obj);
   }
   counter += 1000;
   data.clear();
   em.clear();
   em.close();
}
```

Comment: Did you try increasing heap size maximum with -Xmx ? See: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use native SQL anyway, can't you specify the `LIMIT :counter, 1000` (or `ROWNUM BETWEEN :counter AND 1000` if using Oracle) directly in your SQL statement?

Comment: Well, I am using mysql where we can specify limit but its not allowed by JPA. JPA provides a mechanisim to paginate through set firstResutl and set Max Result which works fine but when counter reaches to 250,000 then it throws heap exception

Comment: Yes, some JPA implementations do paging "in memory", instead of letting the database do that, which is of course nonsense. Does it work with `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()` ?

Comment: only way is to use native query for pagination to prevent from memory leaks. it works thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Note that you create new instance of `EntityManagerFactory` at each iteration, but don't close it. Perhaps it would be better to use a single factory instead:

```
int counter = 0;
EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPU");      
while (counter >= 0) {
    javax.persistence.EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement as you've suggested but still its not releasing memory.